# Excel VBA: Open file in subdirectory by pattern

Tags: excel, vba

I have a directory with folders named like this:

```
"Voy [yyyymmdd]-[no]"
```

where [yyyymmdd] refers to date and [no] increments with one per folder.

```
dir\Voy 20140101-100\*
dir\Voy 20140105-101\*
dir\Voy 20140109-102\*
dir\Voy 20140113-103\*
dir\Voy 20140117-104\*
dir\Voy 20140121-105\*
dir\Voy 20140125-106\*
[...]
```

I'd like do access a file (always named "myfile.xlsx")  in the LATEST folder, that is: the one with the highest [no]

How do I accomplish this?
Should I be using the DIR function referenced [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You may need to adapt this your for your directory and file naming convention

```
Sub GetLatestFiles()
    Dim strDir As String, fs As Object, startFolder As String, subfolder As Object, increment As Integer, latest As Integer, latestFolder As String

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    startFolder = "C:\YourDirectory"
    Set folder = fs.GetFolder(startFolder)
    latest = 0
    latestFolder = vbNullString        

    For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
        increment = CInt(VBA.Right(subfolder.Path, Len(subfolder.Path) - WorksheetFunction.Find("-", subfolder.Path, 1)))

        If increment > latest Then
            latest = increment
            latestFolder = subfolder.Path
        End If
    Next

    Workbooks.Open latestFolder & "\" & "myfile.xlsx"
End Sub
```

- The code loops through all subfolders in the main directory
- For each it makes a note of the version number and keep track of the highest
- Finally it opens the latest workbook

Comment: I get a Type mismatch at line 11: increment = CInt(...  Off-by-1-error?

Comment: disregard previous. need to weed out some other folders. if instr(... should do the trick.

Comment: I got it working after a few adaptations, Thanks a bunch! I tried printing the final value of latestFolder to a cell in my workbook, it was "". Any idea why?

Comment: I am pleased it helped. Not sure about when `latestFolder` is printing `""`. I'll take a look...

Comment: Disregard `latestFolder` issue. I forgot that "-" appears higher up in the `dir` tree. Modified `WorksheetFunction.Find()` to start looking at index 50 and forward.